# mvvmLight EventToCommand strange behavior

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm-light

I try to use EventToCommand in my XAML. Here is sample of this:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding StartCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unloaded">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding StopCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

When I changed WindowStyle to `None`, it stops working. I have to change the code removing "Interaction.Triggers" part from XAMLand add to code-behind following:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _viewModel.StartCommand.Execute(null);
}
```

It will then work again.

Is it a MVVM-Light bug or do I misuse EnevtToCommand? (I'm using MvvmLight version 3.0)

Comment: Add the same event trigger from code-behind, and execute it from inside `Window_Loaded`. By stepping through it with the debugger you will find out why it doesn't work. Looking at the value of `StartCommand` might also give you clues as well.